# Html.ActionLink on Post Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, get

Is there any way that I can use a html.actionLink to post data?

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(TestModel test)
    {
        return View(test);
    }
```

and on my view...

```
    @Html.ActionLink("ClickMe","Test", new {Test1 = "actionLink", Test2 = "actionLinkDidThis"}, FormMethod.Post)
```

Is there any way that this action link could get in the httpPost method and not the httpGet method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will render an anchor tag which will produce a get request since it's a regular hyperlink at the end of the day.
You can Make the action method a Get method though by putting a HttpGet attribute on it instead. The MVC model binder will be able to deserialize the Get request into the TestModel object for Get requests as well.

I would use a button and do a form post if you need a post request

Comment: hmm. Ok! But how would I send a new Model to the httpPost method with button like i'm doing with this actionLink? 'Test1' and 'Test2' are TestModel properties that I wanted to send to the server

Comment: Where are the values coming from?

Comment: Oh yeah, putting only one method worked as well! An this method has the parameter 'TestModel'

Comment: the values are comming from textboxes

Comment: Here's an example of something that sounds similar. http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2010/10/30/an-mvc-3-contact-form.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your time! I manage to get it working, and I'll read the page you sent!